# How to generate PDF from markdown using pure ruby

Tags: ruby, pdf, pdf-generation, markdown

I'm currently using Kramdown to generate HTML from Markdown in Ruby.
I know that I can generate a latex file using kramdown and convert it to pdf usaing a command line utility. But I want a pure ruby solution.

Is there a way to convert markdown to pdf using only ruby without using command-line utilities?

Comment: Same question, any language: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3588/convert-markdown-to-pdf-without-latex

Answer (score 22):

You can use https://github.com/walle/gimli

I made it just for this purpose. Though, I use textile. But gimli supports all formats supported by GitHub-Markup.

Comment: I don't have access to a Windows machine. So I haven't been able to test. What is the problem with running it on Windows?

Comment: Not possible to install all the required components via gems. And then one should configure and debug.

Comment: @FredrikWallgren does it use another backend, or does it have its own?

Comment: @CiroSantilli It uses https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf to generate the PDF from the HTML generated from the markup.

Answer (score 6):

**Prawn: The Pure Ruby PDF Generation Library** 
http://www.rubyinside.com/prawn-ruby-pdf-library-987.html

Answer (score 2):

The `wkhtmltopdf` gem is also available: http://rubygems.org/gems/wkhtmltopdf

Answer (score -2):

Pandoc is a universal document converter which can convert documents in markdown, reStructuredText, textile, HTML, DocBook, or LaTeX to HTML, EPUB, Microsoft Word, TeX, PDF via LaTeX, Lightweight markup formats.

You can find it here.
http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/

Comment: I'm not completely sure if PanDoc is a Ruby solution - also, it cannot directly convert into PDF without a supporting TeX software installed.

Comment: Pandoc is Haskell *and* you need latex.